# Laravel get username in home instead of login button after authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

I have two different user tables. One for student and one for teacher. There is a login button in home page. Homepage is available to all the users and guest. When user authenticates through login he is directed to dashboard (student dashboard and teacher dashboard which are different).

Now all I want is when the user is autheticated this name is show in homepage or if not authenticated login button have to be shown.

```
//In Route.php

Route::get('/', HomeController@home);

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:teacher']), function(){
    Route::get('/teacher/dashboard', 'TeacherController@dashboard');
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:student']), function(){
    Route::get('/student/dashboard', 'StudentController@dashboard');
});

Route::post('/login/student', 'Auth\LoginController@studentLogin');
Route::post('/login/teacher', 'Auth\LoginController@teacherLogin');
```

LoginController.php

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:student')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:teacher')->except('logout');
    }

public function studentLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->intended('/student/dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

public function teacherLogin(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email'   => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);

            if (Auth::guard('teacher')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
                return redirect()->intended('/teacher/dashboard');
            }
            return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
        }
```

Login will redirect me to respective dashboard.

But when I move to homepage though user is authenticated I get not authenticated result.i.e.

> User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button

from the following code in homepage blade.

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ 'User Is Logged In, Show A LogOut Button' }}
@else
    {{ 'User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button' }}
@endif
```

> homepage has login button. when authenticated this login button in
>   home page needs to be replaced by logout button

I'm struggling too much on this. Thank you for a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this all I need to do was check access through 'guard'.

Instead of this:

```
@if(Auth::check())
   {{ 'User Is Logged In, Show A LogOut Button' }}
@else
    {{ 'User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button' }}
@endif
```

need to do this:

```
@if(Auth::guard('teacher')->check())
   {{ 'User Is Logged In, Show A LogOut Button' }}
@else
    {{ 'User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button' }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the user in your `auth` check. Change your code to this:

```
@if(Auth::user())
    {{ 'User Is Logged In, Show A LogOut Button' }}
@else
    {{ 'User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button' }}
@endif
```

**EDIT:**

The `check()` method is used to see if the user exists and if the user is valid (has valid data), it checks if the user is `null` so that you get a `boolean` value. It looks like this:

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

On the other side, `Auth::user()` returns the actual user logged in.

Comment: Actually though I'm logged in I'm not getting logged in result when I'm in homepage but when I navigate to dashboard I get authenticated result @zlatangoralija